# need a larger primitive type for integers

Tags: java, long-integer

I have a java program that multiplies large numbers. The output is a `long`, but it's too small, and the output is 0. I don't think there is a larger primitive type.

The way I could do it is to use the `BigInteger` class, but then I'd have to use it's `multiply()` and `divide()` methods rather than the regular `*` and `/`, which would be very inconvenient.

Here is the line of code:

```
System.out.printf("c) In how many of the arrangements in part (a) are all the vowels adjacent?%n    " + "(7! / (2!2!))(6! / 3!2!) = " + (new Factorial(7).r / new Power(new Factorial(2).r,2).r) * (new Factorial(6).r / (new Factorial(6).r * new Factorial(2).r)) + "%n");
```

It's using my `Factorial` and `Power` classes, and it's too large.

Is there a longer number class that can still use `*` and `/`? Or is there another number class that'll be easier to use?

thanks.

Comment: No. `long` is the longest.

Comment: No, you're basically stuck with `BigInteger`. Also note that backslash isn't an operator - you meant `/`.

Comment: Btw: the line you posted should work fine: http://ideone.com/OfbVMj `!21` would be the first that overflows (and you should not get 0 as result).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primitive types (byte, short, int, long) are classic types that are usually -- in other languages (think C, C++) -- defined by processor architecture. So a long would be either 16-bits, 32-bits or 64-bits depending on your CPU type.

Now Java changed this and fixed this types to certain lengths disregardless of processor architecture. [See more info here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

If you need to work with larger numbers you're only left with `BigInteger`, `BigDecimal` and similar. Mind you: these types do not use CPU instructions but do mathematical operations "by hand", which means they are quite (think 1000x times) slower.

On the other hand, what you are talking about -- using `*` and `/` with these types is called [operator overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading). Some programming languages support it, but in Java it's a big no-no. There are some precompilers (see [JFront](http://www.gginc.biz/jfront/)) but last I heard it doesn't work with `BigInteger`.

You could write your program in [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) or [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/) -- these both run on JVM (Groovy's syntax is quite similar to Java -- mostly just renaming .java to .groovy works) and both support operator overloading for `BigInteger`.

Comment: Operator overloading is "a big no-no"? You make it sound like it's a taboo. Java just doesn't support it, that's all.

Comment: @Jesper What I meant it's not supported in Java and it's not likely to be supported in the future. There's been a lot of controversy around supporting it in Java and they've always decided against it. So yes, it does seem that it's a taboo topic in Java.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using double, which is bigger than a long, and use only the integer part.

Otherwise you could create your own integer class, which will contain two or three longs,
then you use shift and bitwise operators to handle mathematical operations, but it's not easy.

The last solution may be to write c++ code using a very big integer and use the generated exe with java, but this solution would break code portability.

Comment: @Jon note that you'll loose precision if you use `double` instead of `long`. Don't expect exact answers when you use `double`.

Comment: @Jesper i'll take note of that.